# getDefinitionByName("mx.containers.TabNavigator"); does not work

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

when i try to got a flex class (any UIComponent) with getDefinitionByName(), it tells me that that class is not defined (and im using the full path), but if i try to reference a custom made class using the full path, then it works.
My Project is referencing another project btw.

Comment: This is a runtime issue, right?  can you provide some sample code?  Are you sure the class you're trying to access was compiled in the final SWF?  If it was not used; it may not optimized out.  If you're using RSLs; then I'm unclear if you can access classes from the RSL using the getDefinitionByName() approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put this in your code somewhere:

```
var dummy:Array=[mx.containers.TabNavigator];
```

And try again. There is a known issue with Flash compiler, that it does not use class definitions of classes if they are not used anywhere. This will force the compiler to include `mx.containers.TabNavigator` definition in SWF, so that it can be reached by `getDefinitionByName()`.

Comment: well, actually, i hope to find a way without declaring dummy variables, if i find no other way, i will accept your answer

Comment: If you have any variable of type `Class`, write a single assignment of `mx.containers.TabNavigator` to it prior to assigning it the actual value. In fact literally any explicit mention of a class's FQN will force the compiler to include its description into the SWF. That's why I said "anywhere" - it can be a function-local var, and still work.

Comment: so i could make a function which would do those dummy declarations, but i dont have to actually call that function, and it would work, right?, of course i mean to declare that function in the file in which i want to use getDeclarationByName

Comment: I think yes, I have never heard of Flash compiler to optimize class definitions by removing unreferencced functions. Please check if so. I didn't use this trick, I have used a dummy var in a normal way, but I had 100 classes to make available via `getDefinitionByName()`

Comment: I kinda alluded to this answer in my comment on the main question.  The class was being optimized out of your final SWF; which is why saw the runtime error.  If you don't want to create dummy variables, you can do so with a Flex compiler argument to force the class to be compiled into your final SWF.

Comment: I would create dummy declarations like this: `private var dummy:TabNavigator;` without the need for a new array / instance.

Comment: @Reboog711 See, a compiler never includes a definition of a class being extended, because it constructs a new one out of it at compile time and forgets it. It's normal. And about `private var dummy:TabNavigator` - this enlarges the class's signature by ~16 bytes, which might be an issue if your SWF is already memory-hungry and the class you put this in has more than 1000 simultaneous instances. Putting this into a function (best possible IMHO is Main's constructor) does no memory overhead.

Comment: Just to clarify: this is definitely not an issue, but works as intended. By default the compiler only compiles classes that have been referenced in your source code. Otherwise the compiler would need to add ALL classes it has access to; it would make your swfs massive. However you can also tell the compiler to explicitly include specific classes with the [`includes` compiler option](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7a92.html), i.e. you don't _have_ to create the dummy declarations.

Comment: Are you saying that `private var dummy:TabNavigator` enlarges the class signature, but `var dummy:Array=[mx.containers.TabNavigator];` does not?  If so, you should add that elaboration to your main answer--that the code you displayed should go in a constructor.  With Flex, you can use the `include class` compiler argument to include a class: http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=compilers_14.html which should have nothing to do w/ class being extended or not.  Just as @Creynders stated in his followup.

Comment: @Reboog711 see, `private` is only valid in class variables, while plain `var` can exist inside a function and not reflect on a class signature. About `include class` - yes, of course, but I dare you including 100+ classes this way. Note that compiler options string should then also be maintained with this approach, while a dummy var is a fire-and-forget approach, which is IMHO generally better.

Comment: @Vesper cleanest solution is to add them to a flex config file.

Comment: @Vesper Have you ever needed to include 100+ classes that way?  I've never had to do more than one or two in any given app.  Usually it is Value Objects returned from a server in arrays that are not accessed directly in code through other means.

Comment: @Reboog711 I have 100+ embedded images with assigned class names like `[String][Number]` with strings listed elsewhere for reference purposes. Then, to make an instance of such a class (I need one of each) I used a loop `for each(var s:String in stringList) for (i=1;i<10;i++) {... new GetDefinitionByName(s+i.toString)().bitmapData...}` which required all of those classes to be included in compilation. Apparently, FlashDevelop/AS3 decided not to, so I had to name them all in a dummy var.